# net.sourceforge.stripes.exception.StripesServletException: Could not create instance of ActionBean type

Tags: instantiation, stripes

While I was working on creating a new stripes action, I found the following error on a log file.

```
**net.sourceforge.stripes.exception.StripesServletException: ***Could not create instance of ActionBean type*** [site.person.inspector.finaid.budget.ManageSession].**
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.AnnotatedClassActionResolver.getActionBean(AnnotatedClassActionResolver.java:368)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.NameBasedActionResolver.getActionBean(NameBasedActionResolver.java:264)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.AnnotatedClassActionResolver.getActionBean(AnnotatedClassActionResolver.java:293)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherHelper$1.intercept(DispatcherHelper.java:106)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.ExecutionContext.proceed(ExecutionContext.java:158)
    at.site.stripesext.ConnectionContextSetupInterceptor.intercept(ConnectionContextSetupInterceptor.java:17)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.ExecutionContext.proceed(ExecutionContext.java:155)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.BeforeAfterMethodInterceptor.intercept(BeforeAfterMethodInterceptor.java:113)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.ExecutionContext.proceed(ExecutionContext.java:155)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.ExecutionContext.wrap(ExecutionContext.java:74)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherHelper.resolveActionBean(DispatcherHelper.java:102)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherServlet.resolveActionBean(DispatcherServlet.java:238)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:141)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.StripesFilter.doFilter(StripesFilter.java:247)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at .site.person.PersonAuditFilter.doFilter(PersonAuditFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at .site.support.security.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at .site.support.session.SessionTrackingFilter.doFilter(SessionTrackingFilter.java:41)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at .site.support.security.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:39)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at .site.support.downtime.DowntimeFilter.doFilter(DowntimeFilter.java:41)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at .site.QueueFilter.doFilter(QueueFilter.java:23)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at .site.TransactionFilter.doFilter(TransactionFilter.java:82)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at .site.ExceptionLoggingFilter.doFilter(ExceptionLoggingFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at .site.PdfFilter.doFilter(PdfFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at .site.PreventCacheResponseFilter.doFilter(PreventCacheResponseFilter.java:25)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at site.QuiesceFilter.doFilter(QuiesceFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at .site.HqlTraceFilter.doFilter(HqlTraceFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at .site.AuditFilter.doFilter(AuditFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.FastCommonAccessLogValve.invoke(FastCommonAccessLogValve.java:500)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:873)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Below are the classes that I am working for right now.

```
@UrlBinding("/person/inspect/finaid/budget/manage-session-budget.page")
public class ManageSession extends AbstractAidApplicantYearSessionTab{
//The class AbstractAidApplicantYearSessionTab has a hierarchy and the last one extends from UIAction
    private static final String MANAGE_JSP_FILE="person/inspect/finaid/budget/manage-session-budget.jsp"  ;
    @Override
    @DefaultHandler
    public Resolution show() {
        return new MauiForwardResolution(MANAGE_JSP_FILE);
    }

    public ManageSession(PersonInspectorAction personInspector, String group, String title) {
           super(personInspector, group, title);
       }

}


@UrlBinding("/person/inspect/finaid/budget/cost-of-attendance.page")

public class CostOfAttendanceTab extends AbstractAidApplicantTab {

public String getViewSessionUrl() {
        return "/person/inspect/finaid/budget/manage-session-budget.page";
    }

public CostOfAttendanceTab(PersonInspectorAction personInspector, String group, String     title) {
    super(personInspector, group, title);
}


}
```

What I am trying to do is when you click a link I calls the getViewSessionUrl (i.e actionBean.viewSessionUrl). which in turn takes you to the manage-session-budget.page (i.e class ManageSession)… In that class I have a default resolution called show().. which forwards you to the manage-session-budget.jsp …. but I don’t know why it is not getting that jsp file or sth is wrong with the ManageSession page …

Do you have any thought?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action bean class (`ManageSession`), doesn't have a no-arg constructor, so Stripes can't create an instance of this class.

Comment: Well. You are right 'ManageSession' doesn't have a no-arg constructor. So do the other classes like 'CostOfAttendance' and they work well. Even I tried to put a default constructor in the ManageSession and it has a compile time error that says There is no default constructor available in site.person.inspector.finaid.AbstractAidApplicantYearSessionTab (the parent of ManageSession). When I do the same thing in AbstractAidApplicantYearSessionTab , it keeps pointing me to the parent class and so on. I don't have right to change other classes except ManageSession. What should i do?

Comment: The CostOfAttendanceTab class does have a no-arg constructor, because it doesn't have any, and in this case, the Java compiler creates one for you, which just calls `super()`. The no-arg constructor **must** call a super constructor as its first instruction. If the superclass doesn't have a no-arg constructor, then another one must be called explicitely: `public ManageSession() {super(null, null, null);// ...}`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: I am sorry. There is already a constructor in CostOfAttendanceTab. I edited my question.
public CostOfAttendanceTab(PersonInspectorAction personInspector, String group, String title) {
        super(personInspector, group, title);
    }

Comment: Then I don't see how it could be instantiated by Stripes. Why don't you use your debugger and execute the getActionBean method instruction by instruction. You'll see that it ends up calling `type.newInstance()`, which expects a no-arg constructor. BTW, the "caused by" in the full stack trace should contain the original exception.

Comment: Aghhh...spent more than a day on this problem finally to find out there is a place where the company's framework instantiate this actionBeans. Unless you have worked for a long time (or at least in most parts of the company's framework) there is no way to find out the solution for such problems. Any ways, since your answer makes sense I will mark it as the solution. Thanks a lot.